# Hibernate Envers and Hibernate Auto Flush

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I've got a Spring application using Hibernate. I've implemented Envers into it, which is working fine. However, Hibernate will by default automatically flush before some transactions are committed.

For example, I have an MVC endpoint that will update a record, but before saving it, will have to make various other queries to retrieve some other data. Each time another query is run, Hibernate flushes and this results in there being multiple audit rows for each change. This creates some confusion, as there is already a modified date on my record which isn't changed in each update (as it's flushing before this property is changed).

What are my options for managing this more effectively, and creating a reliable audit log even with Hibernate flushing in this way? Is the only answer to implement my own listener with some custom logic to check if it should actually be committing an audit change or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can detach the entity and merge when you are done. These queries are only executed if they touch tables that would be affected by pending inserts/updates/deletes. If you use native queries, this is a different topic. Hibernate has no SQL parser to figure out which tables you are touching so it is conservative and flushes all pending changes.